# How to save image from web site to iphone app in background (and to do that fast)?

Tags: iphone, ios

I found on some forum post about saving image from web site to iphone app and I'm using it because everything is ok with it except one thing, speed.

Image is about 10KB and it's downloaded with ok speed when there is one image, but when there are 15-20 images it's very slow.

I know there must be way to download image faster on another way becase I have some news apps on my iPhone and this apps download 15-20 articles with images like my (I say like my because quality is the same or better) and is about 5 seconds faster (or more).

So my question is; Is there another faster way to download images from website to iPhone app?

This is my code:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1

#import "downloadImage.h"

@interface downloadImage ()

@end

@implementation downloadImage

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *imgUrl = @"http://somesite.com/someimage.jpg";

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadImageFromWeb:) withObject:imgUrl waitUntilDone:YES];

    });

}

-(void)downloadImageFromWeb:(NSString *)imgUrl{


    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]]];

    NSArray *parts = [imgUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    NSString *imgFilename = [parts lastObject];

    [self saveImage:image:imgFilename];

}


- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image:(NSString*)imageName {

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          imageName];

    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

    //NSLog(@"image saved");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't see the part of the question which is related to Xcode... Or maybe there isn't one?

Comment: You should probably be using NSURLConnection to download the image.

Comment: downloading image depends on speed of internet as well as server

Comment: @Prince - if I'm using same local internet for all my apps and speed of server is extra fast there must be problem in code :)

Comment: why you are using like this `dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadImageFromWeb:) withObject:imgUrl waitUntilDone:YES];

    });` ? Change it to `dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        [self downloadImageFromWeb:imgUrl];

    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) check the actual load time for this image from a normal browser, this might be a server-side issue

2) try to use some proven code for this, like [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) and see if there is any difference with yours.

3) remove saving and test again. If it goes faster, subthread the saving (however, it is not good idea to create so many threads)

4) why do you perform load selector on main thread ? Do it on background thread and later update the image on the main one. The way you are dispatching it now it blocks the main thread.

Comment: AsyncImageView rock's :) Is this script safe and Apple confirm this script?

Comment: its being used like in 10k apps approved apps, so, don't worry :)

Answer (score 1):

Downloading image depends on `speed` of `internet` as well as `server`.

If do not want to bother `UI` of `application` while downloading then perform downloading in `Background process`:

```
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImageFromWeb:) withObject:imgUrl waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I'm already downloading in background what you can see in my first post.

Comment: sorry, now I understand. I will test it up.

Comment: ...but I'm getting error: No visible @interface for 'downloadImage' declares the selector 'performSelectorInBackground:withObject:waitUntilDone:'

Answer (score 0):

```
dataWithContentsOfURL
```

is a synchronous call. Us `NSConnection` and in `connectionDidFinishedLoading` get main que and set image to wherever you want. This will run in background

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dispatch_async` is a better choice. But in your case this line causes the issue:

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadImageFromWeb:) withObject:imgUrl waitUntilDone:YES];

    });
```

Change the code like:

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

            [self downloadImageFromWeb:imgUrl];

        });
```

Please refer these documents:

[Performance : dispatch_async](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async)

[ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

This is a good [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial%29) for you to handle such situations.